# Connect-AzureAd is not recognized

Tags: azure, powershell

I am trying to make this command working on my MAC OS and even installing all modules I have found in other blogs, like AzureAD, AzureADPreview.¨. I still get the same message. Can someone please give me some clue about fixing?

```
Connect-AzureAD: The term 'Connect-AzureAD' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.

                                                         
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      7.0.3
PSEdition                      Core
GitCommitId                    7.0.3
OS                             Darwin 19.6.0 Darwin Kernel Version 19.6.0: Mon Aug 31 22:12:52 PDT 2020; root:xnu-6153.141.2~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Platform                       Unix
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0…}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
WSManStackVersion              3.0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact you're getting an error message suggesting the cmdlet isn't recognized points to the fact you haven't installed or imported the correct module. Important to note regarding [AzureAD module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/?view=azureadps-2.0) is generally not used, you should generally be aiming to use the [AZ module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.accounts/?view=azps-4.8.0) where possible.

If you're specifically looking to use `AzureAD` then use can use the following

```
Register-PackageSource -Trusted -ProviderName 'PowerShellGet' -Name 'Posh Test Gallery' -Location https://www.poshtestgallery.com/api/v2/
Install-Module AzureAD.Standard.Preview
import-Module AzureAD.Standard.Preview
```

I would suggest you use the `AZ Module` using:

```
Install-Module az
Import-Module az
```

for the cmdlet `connect-azureAD` you can use `connect-azaccount`

Because you're using a Mac you won't be met with windows prompt to login, you'll be given a link you'll need to manually use to log into for auth.

Comment: Yeah,  I'am using Connect-AzAccount, but I didn't know why Connect-AzureAD doesn't  work on MacOS. Thanks Matthew.

Comment: @m4u2o it's more that AzureAD as a module isn't really the main Azure related module anymore it would be Az - I still use AzureAD myself for cmdlets like `get-azureADdevice` but on a MacOS the best bet is to use the above preview version

Comment: thanks for solution, you should edit to remove the ' at the end of url